# Promoting a postgres slave to master node

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave, postgresql-11

I have two `postgresql 11.4` running as master and slave nodes.

I am inserting huge volume of data in master to see it get replicated on the slave.
Trying to simulate the following case,

- Insert huge data
- `pause_wal_replay` on slave
- wait for the wal files to get shipped to slave
- `resume_wal_replay` on slave
- promote immediately when there are multiple wal files waiting to be replayed

If a `promote signal` is issued at this point [ When there are multiple wal - already shipped and waiting to be replayed ], When will slave promote itself?

1. After replaying all the existing wal files [ `shipped and waiting to be replayed` ]
   or
2. Immediately after receiving promote signal. [ `Without replaying the wal files` waiting - `causing data loss` ? ]

If it is `(1)`, what happens if the master node is still sending wal files and I try to promote the slave. Does it ignore the incoming wal and promote itself?

Hoping PG Experts can shed light on this.

PS : I'm issuing promote signal by creating a '`pg_failover_trigger`' if its worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is promoted, the standby server shuts down the WAL receiver process and recovers all remaining WAL it has. So we get the behavior from 1.